# Can't get cookies with js-cookie and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, js-cookie

I'm using Nextjs and trying to make multi language application. Multi langugage working properly but when I'm trying get language code with cookie like 'en', getting error.

**This way working;**

```
initialLang = 'en';
setDefaultTranslations({en, fr});
setLanguage('en');
```

But when I'm trying to set initialLang with cookie not working.

**This way not working**

```
initialLang = Cookies.get('lang');
setDefaultTranslations({en, fr});
setLanguage(initialLang);
```

Comment: What is the value of `Cookies.get('lang');`?

Comment: 'en' or 'fr'. changing with click function.

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(typeof Cookies.get('lang'));`?

Comment: Output is 'string'

Comment: Strange... sorry, can’t figure this one out.

Comment: When you reload the page, is `Cookies.get('lang');` still set?

Comment: Yes it's set. console.log output 'en' but not working in the function.

Comment: Are you getting an error or something? And when you say "not working in the function," what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Yes i've got an error but it's not about cookies. It's return Lang string is not found. Because cookies not passing value setLanguage function.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem you need to step back and understand the problem. The main problem about the cookie is you need to split your code to read&write cookie for server and client. js-cookie works for only client-side. Basically, it works on the client because it works with `document.cookie`. When it calls `document` in next.js SSR, the backend code is not able to read the `document` because it does not exist. If you would like to read cookie in SSR you need to catch it from expressjs `request` and pass into react state. I would recommend you to use https://github.com/andreizanik/cookies-next which already solves this problem (implementation)

Answer (score -1):

Probably, you're not using them in componentDidMount hook:

```
componentDidMount() {
  // get cookie
  // set state to update the language
}
```

Comment: I'm tried but still getting error. Error is 'lang is not selected'.

Comment: You'll need to initialize and update the state instead of some variable.

Comment: I'm trying this and different methods but not working. Really amazing...